# Install package on OS X 10.11.5 using apt-get

Tags: software-installation, osx

**Problem:**

I am trying to figure out whether it is even possible to install the software GTK Vector Screenshot, which can be found here:

- https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Gtk_vector_screenshot/
- https://github.com/nomeata/gtk-vector-screenshot

According to information I found `apt-get` is not available on OS X and you should instead install Homebrew.

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to install this software at all on OS X 10.11.5?
- If yes, how?
- If no, why not?

I have looked through the installation instructions on Github but I am not at the technical level to understand how you should proceed with the installation using Terminal on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a package manager like Yum or APT, no there is not similar built-in package manager. Without using a package manager, you cannot download from the net - repositories. The only option you have is compile your code.

But if you're looking for a package manager, I recommend you use either [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) or [Mac Ports](https://www.macports.org). I've worked with both, and they work well. Most of the times Homebrew is fairly enough, but the choice is yours.

But if you're just looking for a vector screenshot software, you can change your screenshots to be taken by default in vector-based `.PDF` or whatsoever - while OS X by default uses its `screencapture` type as `.png` - but this is a bit meaningless to do so since they are taken from the pixels.

Comment: I tried download GTK Vector Screenshot using Homebrew through the command `brew install gtk-vector-screenshot`. However, this did not work and I received the message `Error: No available formula for gtk-vector-screenshot`.

Comment: NetBSD's [pkgsrc](https://www.pkgsrc.org/) also works well on OS X (for the BSD inclined), but I'm not using any X11 packages from there so I can't say anything about that.

Comment: @Kusalananda Affirmative.

Comment: @kexxcream Does homebrew include this package?

Comment: @FarazX Does not seem to be the case. If it's not included, it won't be possible to install it any other way?

Comment: @kexxcream no, but as far as I know, it's not possible to take a screen shot in vector format, since the screenshots are simply taken from the pixels shown on- or off-scree. What you need, can be done with the help of Adobe Illustrator. And as you might know, screen shots in Mac OS X can be taken by ⌘+Shift+3 or if you want just a part of your screen, you can use ⌘+Shift+4, that's all I know. I haven't installed UI associated tools from brew, but I know it works well for command line tools since I've worked with it.

Comment: @FarazX I only ask because of what I read here http://superuser.com/questions/473765/can-i-take-a-screenshot-as-vector-graphics-or-at-a-higher-resolution-than-native/613888#613888

Comment: @kexxcream I recommend you read [this on AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113869/is-it-possible-to-take-a-screenshot-in-vector-format), [this one on discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4762067?tstart=0). No, this is not possible at least on Mac OS X, you can change your screenshot to be by default in .PDF or whatsoever, but they cannot be in vector format since they are taken from the pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Per previous answer, yes, there are some packet managers for OSX
But, there are only working packages.
gtk-vector-screenshot can be applied only on working GTK environment, which osx is not. So, there is no way and reason to build this application, since gtk isn't used in osx.

I bet you can try [some raster to vector convertors](https://www.google.ru/?client=safari#newwindow=1&q=raster%20to%20vector%20converter), converting your usual screenshots to svg format.

This was also discussed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113869/is-it-possible-to-take-a-screenshot-in-vector-format)

Comment: OS X is able to run X11 applications, including those built for GTK. The problem is rather that none of the available package managers carry that particular package.

Comment: I know it, but I bet the question is about taking any screenshot on OS X in vector format. Can't really remember any gtk-only app that I had to run on my machine, at least